# Check multiple levels of folders is dir

Tags: php, codeigniter

When user types in a new folder name and the name all ready exists in sub folders and main folder then will return error.

Currently it returns error even if folder not exist in sub folders etc.

> **Question** How can I make it so that it can check main directory and sub folders and return error if exits else lets me create it.

The post for foldername is  `$this->input->post('folder')`

Checks if any subfolders exists with same name.

```
if (!$json) {

    $results = scandir($DIR_IMAGE);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_dir($DIR_IMAGE . '/' . $result)) {
            $json['error'] = 'This folder name all ready';
        }
    }
}
```

Full Function

```
public function folder() {

    $json = array();

    $DIR_IMAGE = FCPATH . 'images/';

    if ($this->input->get('directory')) {
        $directory =  $this->input->get('directory') . '/';
    } else {
        $directory = 'catalog/';
    }

    if (!$json) {
        $arrPathParts = explode('/', $directory);

        if (count($arrPathParts) > 3) {
            $json['error'] = 'You can not create a new folder here try back one level.';
        }
    }

    if (!$json) {

        $re = '/\W/'; // \W matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])

        $str = $this->input->post('folder');

        $is_correct_foldername = !preg_match($re, $str) ? true : false; 

        if (!$is_correct_foldername) {
            $json['error'] = 'You have some symbols or no spaces that are not allowed';
        }
    }

    // Checks if any subfolders exists with same name.

    if (!$json) {

        $results = scandir($DIR_IMAGE);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

            if (is_dir($DIR_IMAGE . '/' . $result)) {
                $json['error'] = 'This folder name all ready';
            }
        }
    }

    // Every thing passes now will create folder
    if (!$json) {
        mkdir($DIR_IMAGE . $directory . $this->input->post('folder'), 0777, true);
        $json['success'] = 'Your folder is now created!';
    }

    $this->output->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($json));        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```php
if (!$json) {

    $results = scandir($DIR_IMAGE);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_dir($DIR_IMAGE . '/' . $result)) {
            $json['error'] = 'This folder name all ready';
        }
    }
}
```

You are only checking whethe each directory name returned from `scandir()` is a directory - which would always be `true`.

Assuming the name of the directory you want to check for is `$this->input->post('foldername')`, you can do:

```php
if (!$json) {

    $results = scandir($DIR_IMAGE);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        if ($result === '.' or $result === '..') continue;

        if (is_dir($DIR_IMAGE . '/' . $result) && ($result == $this->input->post('foldername'))) {
            $json['error'] = 'This folder name all ready';
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should try to use the `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant instead of `'/'` directory.

Finally, also be careful that directory name capitalisation could be a factor on different operating systems.

Comment: Where can I place this `$this->input->post('foldername');`  because that gets the user folder name is trying to create.

Comment: I've edited my answer to indicate where it should be placed. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have found away using RecursiveTreeIterator and in_array now works fine now. I posted my own answer for other people.

Answer (score 0):

I have now got a solution using RecursiveIteratorIterator and in array

```
public function folder() {

    $json = array();

    $DIR_IMAGE = FCPATH . 'images/';

    if ($this->input->get('directory')) {
        $directory =  $this->input->get('directory') . '/';
    } else {
        $directory = 'catalog/';
    }

    if (!$json) {
        $arrPathParts = explode('/', $directory);

        if (count($arrPathParts) > 3) {
            $json['error'] = 'You can not create a new folder here try back one level.';
        }
    }

    if (!$json) {

        $re = '/\W/'; // \W matches any non-word character (equal to [^a-zA-Z0-9_])

        $str = $this->input->post('folder');

        $is_correct_foldername = !preg_match($re, $str) ? true : false; 

        if (!$is_correct_foldername) {
            $json['error'] = 'You have some symbols or no spaces that are not allowed';
        }
    }

    // Checks if any subfolders exists with same name. @todo clean paths

    if (!$json) {

        $root = $DIR_IMAGE . 'catalog/';

        $iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($root, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST,
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD // Ignore "Permission denied"
        );

        $paths = array($root);

        foreach ($iter as $path => $dir) {
            if ($dir->isDir()) {
                $paths[] = basename($path);
            }
        }

        if (in_array($this->input->post('folder'), $paths)) {
            $json['error'] = 'You have all ready created a folder called ' . $this->input->post('folder') . ' in one of your directories!';
        }
    }

    if (!$json) {
        mkdir($DIR_IMAGE . $directory . $this->input->post('folder'), 0777, true);
        $json['success'] = 'Your folder is now created!';
    }

    $this->output->set_content_type('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($json));        
}
```